# GoogleMaps SDK 1.10.21020.0 Update iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, google-maps, cocoapods

Just trying to update my GoogleMaps SDK version for an iOS application. I'm running Xcode 7.1 and following the directions at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start. Unfortunately I cannot seem to run the following:

```
pod install
```

in the terminal. I have tried to add the '$(inherited)' flag into my project, deleting and recreating my Podfile, updating pod, etc. but nothing seems to let me update the SDK. Below is the code the terminal spits out after I run the pod install command:

```
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using GoogleMaps (1.10.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total
pod installed.

[!] CocoaPods was not able to update the `master` repo. If this is an unexpected issue and persists you can inspect it running `pod repo update --verbose`

[!] The `projectName [Debug]` target overrides the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `projectName [Release]` target overrides the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not updated the gems. Try **sudo gem install cocoapods**
then clean the project `cmd + shift + k`. Then in your Framework Search Path (in build settings) use `$inherited`. then install a podfile and mention all the dependencies you need. This procedure might help you

Comment: Thanks a million mate, I also had to run the following:1)`pod repo remove master`
2)`pod setup`